# Cut mask out of image with certain pixel margin numpy opencv

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I am playing around with the Mask RCNN (https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) segmentation program that is trained on the COCO data set. It detects persons (along with many other objects that I further neglect) in an image and returns one or multiple Person masks, i.e. Boolean Numpy arrays containing True values for all pixels that are classified as a 'Person' and False values for all other pixels:

[image: Overlay Image]

So an inputted image (uint8 array of shape (3900,2922,3)) becomes a mask (Boolean array of shape (3900,2922)) or multiple masks when multiple persons are detected in the picture.

Now I can use this mask to cut the person out of the image with some simply Numpy array indexing:

```
mask3d = np.dstack([mask]*3)
cut_out_mask = np.invert(mask3d)
res = np.where(cut_out_mask, 0, image)
```

This returns the following image:
[image: Cut_out Image]

Since the masks that are returned by the Mask_RCNN program are quite tight, I would like to add a margin of a few pixels (let's say 15px), so that I get something like this:

[image: manual]

Which Numpy/ OpenCV functions can I leverage to cut out the mask from the original image (similar to `np.where`), adding a margin of 15 pixels around the mask?

Comment: You're looking for `cv2.dilate`. The idea is to dilate the mask then bitwise-and with the original input image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you are looking for is the `cv2.filter2D()`.

I wrote a short demo for you:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
```

First we create a demo mask, with contains a square in the middle:

```
mask = np.zeros((300, 300))
mask[100:200, 100:200] = 1
```

Then we create our kernel for the filter2D function:

```
kernel = np.ones((32, 32))
```

I used the size 32, to get the desired padding of 15 pixel.

```
paddedMask = cv2.filter2D(mask, 1, kernel)
```

Just for demoing I display the Image with the following code:

```
image = cv2.threshold(np.array(paddedMask, dtype=np.uint8), 1, 255, 1)[1]
cv2.imshow("Test", image)
cv2.imshow("Org", mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: What is `array` in `paddedMask = cv2.filter2D(mask, 1, array)` ? Guess you mean `kernel` here ?

Comment: What is `padding` in `image = cv2.threshold(np.array(padding, type=np.uint8), 1, 255, 1)[1]` ?

Comment: @DirkSchiller Thanks for the comment. I updated the post and hope it is better to understand. Your questions should be answered by the post know.

Answer (score 4):

One method to do this is to use [`cv2.dilate`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#dilation) to increase the surface area of the mask. Depending on your mask shape, you can create varying structuring element shapes and sizes with [`cv2.getStructuringElement`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#structuring-element).

For instance, if your mask shape is rectangular you might want to use `cv2.MORPH_RECT` or if your mask shape is circular you can use `cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE`. In addition, you can change the kernel size and the number of iterations to dilate. After dilating the mask, you can use [`cv2.bitwise_and`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#bitwise-and) to get your result. Here's a minimum reproducible example:

Original image

[image]

Mask

[image]

Dilate

[image]

Bitwise-and for result

[image]

```
import cv2

# Load image and mask
image = cv2.imread('1.png')
mask = cv2.imread('mask.png')

# Create structuring element, dilate and bitwise-and
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (25,25))
dilate = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=3)
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image, dilate)

cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use [cv2.dilate](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/erosion_dilatation/erosion_dilatation.html#dilation) morphological operation for widening the mask:

```
new_mask = cv2.dilate(mask, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (50,50)))
```

Sample code that loads a mask and widens the mask:

```
import cv2

# Read the mask from a file (for testing).
mask = cv2.imread("sample_mask.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

new_mask = cv2.dilate(mask, cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (50,50)))

# Display mask and new_mask
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('new_mask', new_mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

mask:
[image]

new_mask:
[image]